# Error in Longest Increasing Subsequence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I am trying to implement the Longest Increasing Subsequence in Python [by refering the video here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/longest-increasing-subsequent/problem).

I think I have done it correct. A Dry Run of the code also looks fine to me. But the output is incorrect.

```
d = [3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1]
l = []
l.append([d[0]])

for i in range(1, len(d)):
    l.append([])
    for j in range(0, i):
        if d[j] < d[i] and len(l[i]) < len(l[j]) + 1:
            l[i] = l[j]
    l[i].append(d[i])

print(l)
```

Expected Output: `[[3], [2], [2, 6], [2, 4], [2, 4, 5], [1]]`

Actual Output: `[[3], [2, 6, 4, 5], [2, 6, 4, 5], [2, 6, 4, 5], [2, 6, 4, 5], [1]]`

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the output you got?

Comment: My bad. Should have mentioned that. Have edited the question.

Comment: Why are `[3, 6]`, `[3, 4]`, `[3, 5]`, `[3, 4, 5]`, `[2, 5]` and `[4, 5]` not in your expected output?

Comment: New to dynamic programming. The link says that:L[i] contains the longest increasing subsequence that ends in D[i]

Comment: @blhsing Read the definition on the site. The LIS searches for the longest ascending subsequence that ends with the value of D[i]

Comment: @blhsing Thats true. But to solve the problem using dynamic programming with better time complexity, L[i] is defined in that manner. Please do have a look at the video. It explains both approaches- with and without using dynamic programming

Comment: You should revise your expected output because those are just examples of what potential increasing subsequences can be, not the expected output. The expected output is just a simple integer, the length of the longest possible increasing subsequence given the input sequence.

Comment: Expected output is the output of the above snippet. Do a dry run and you will get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just another referencing problem.

```
for i in range(1, len(d)):
    l.append([])
    for j in range(0, i):
        if d[j] < d[i] and len(l[i]) < len(l[j]) + 1:
            l[i] = l[j]
    l[i].append(d[i])
```

Note the line `l[i] = l[j]`, that makes `l[i]` the same list as `l[j]`, so when you modify `l[i]` later, `l[j]` gets modified too. You probably want a copy here:

```
l[i] = l[j][:]
l[i] = list(l[j])
l[i] = l[j].copy()  # Python 3.3 or up
```

These 3 lines are equivalent so pick one you like.

Comment: Its getting timeout at Hackerrank for few test cases. Is it because of the long time in copying?

Comment: @DeepBodra Of course. You need to optimize the code (in other ways).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Oh! coding is so tricky! Found that copying using ":" is the fastest way to copy. Looks like I will have to search for more efficient algorithms

Comment: @DeepBodra Yes. You probably shouldn't be copying the list. You would like to instead "create information about the previous lists" and reconstruct the lists at the end.